# Handling of iAd in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I have some following requirements, I don't know can we do this in iPhone or not.
Requirements are like

```
1.Can i open ad in safari browser after click.

2.Can i open ad in application itself in webView.

3.If i open ad in webview in that if i click particular link that link can open in safari browser.
```

If anyone knows all this. please help me. I will appreciate. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how iAd works, with iAd you implement the ad banner, and Apple pushes you content to fill it with, which you have VERY limited control over.

To do what you're asking I recommend that you make your own ad, but not an iAd. Doing this you can make whatever you want(within reason) happen when the user clicks it.

Ex.

```
- (void)callUpAd
{
UIView *myAdSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
//add your ad material here
[self.view addSubview:myAdSubView];
}
```